# Database insertions in a reactive loop

Tags: java, rx-java

I have the following method where I am doing db insertions. I want to perform the inserts in a transaction.
Meaning when there are 100 values in records, I wan to insert them all and commit once.

How could I amend the following such that I can get record.value() info for each insert queries below.
This would essentially equate to having andThen() a 100 times but of course I do not want to write andThen() a 100 times nor do I know the number of records which can vary.
To note: Using RX Java 1.
Please advice. Thank you.

```
public Observable<?> insert(Observable<Record<String, String>> records) {
    
// I am looking for a way to get this record.value() into the following return block. 
records.flatMap(record -> {
    String value = record.value();
    return null;
});

return client.rxGetConnection()
        // making it transactional by setting to false 
        .flatMap(connection -> connection.rxSetAutoCommit(false)
                // was looking to insert above records and flatMap operations here but it is not possible from what I have explored. 
                .toCompletable()
                // .andThen(connection.rxExecute("INSERT (name) VALUES " + record.value()) // trying to achieve this, to be able to get record.value for each insert
                .andThen(connection.rxExecute("INSERT (name) VALUES some_value"))
                .flatMap(rows -> connection.rxCommit())).toObservable();
```

}